# How to Load Laravel 5 settings on a Custom PHP Script?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm writing a script which is not using the whole Laravel Environment, so ideally I only need some bits of the whole framework.

I need to fetch the settings in the .env files and possibly be able to use the database via the query builder (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database) instead of the ORM.

Any suggestion on how can I do it?

Comment: If you don't want to use whole Laravel framework, you could use at libraries to implement just what you want (like `dotenv` for loading .env files https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv). Or you could look into Lumen, which is simplified version of Laravel (aimed at developing APIs).

Comment: This one was the library I was looking for. Laravel is already using it, so I don't need to install anything else.

Thanks so much ;)